# How to run Spring Boot App with multiple CommandLineRunner

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, command-line-interface

I am trying to run a Spring Boot Application with multiple CommandLineRunner implementations in hope, that all run methods will be started.

But it is only one of them, anyway both Implementations are created.

First:

```
@Component
public class TestRunnerA implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("starting: TestRunnerA");
        consume();
    }
}
```

Second:

```
   @Component
   public class TestRunnerB implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            logger.info("starting: TestRunnerB");
            consume();
        }
    }
```

In this case, only the `Run()` Method of  `TestRunnerA` ist called.

Does somebody know why?

I tried adding a `@Order` annotation, but still... (the first in the order is called)

Kind regards,
Knut

Comment: I found my Problem, since they are called synced, their run methods are called one bye one, but I am starting a while loop in each, hence only the first one was starting.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate different runners with different spring profiles and specify required profile in your launching script using:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=YourProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a single `SpringBootApplication` that implements `CommandLineRunner` then inject all the other runners as `@Component` and use the first argument to delegate which command should take the rest of the arguments. Here is an example in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58777948/986160

**Important**: be careful though if you put it in a crontab one call will destroy the previous one if it is not done.