# Multiple Spring boot CommandLineRunner based on command line argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-task

I have created spring boot application with spring cloud task which should executes a few commands(tasks). 
Each task/command is shorted-lived task, and all tasks are start from command line, do some short ETL job and finish execution.

There is one spring boot jar which contain all the commands/tasks.
Each task is CommandLineRunner, and I like to decide which tasks (one or more) will be executed based on the params from command line.
What is the best practice to do so?
I don't like to have dirty code which ask "if else" or something like this.

Comment: If you have multiple main classes in the jar file, then you can issue `java -classpath myapp.jar com.example.Task1` on the command line instead of `java -jar myapp.jar`. No if-else anywhere in sight. Why the hate for if-else though? Program's got to branch some times.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure that spring boot allow using multiple main classes. Using hardcoded if-else its harder to maintain then inject components

Answer (score 12):

You can also make your CommandLineRunner implementations @Component and @ConditionalOnExpression("${someproperty:false}")

then have multiple profiles, that set someproperty to true to include those CommandLineRunners in the Context.

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
@ConditionalOnExpression("${myRunnerEnabled:false}")
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String ... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("this ran");
    }
}
```

and in the yml application-myrunner.yml

```
myRunnerEnabled: true
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMain {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution when an application as well as another dependent artifact both have implemented CommandLineRunner. Without this solution, both the implementation classes get executed.

Answer (score 10):

Spring Boot runs all the `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner` beans from the application context. You cannot select one by any args.

So basically you have two possibiities:

1. You have different `CommandLineRunner` implementations and in each you check the arguments to determine if this special `CommandLineRunner` should run.
2. You implement only one `CommandLineRunner` which acts as a dispatcher. Code might look something like this:

This is the new Interface that your runners will implement:

```
public interface MyCommandLineRunner {
    void run(String... strings) throws Exception;
}
```

You then define implementations and identify them with a name:

```
@Component("one")
public class MyCommandLineRunnerOne implements MyCommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCommandLineRunnerOne.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("running");
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component("two")
public class MyCommandLineRunnerTwo implements MyCommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCommandLineRunnerTwo.class);
    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("running");
    }
}
```

Then in your single `CommandLineRunner` implementation you get hold of the application context and resolve the required bean by name, my example uses just the first argument, and call it's `MyCommandLineRunner.run()`method:

```
@Component
public class CommandLineRunnerImpl implements CommandLineRunner, ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        if (strings.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no args given");
        }

        String name = strings[0];
        final MyCommandLineRunner myCommandLineRunner = applicationContext.getBean(name, MyCommandLineRunner.class);
        myCommandLineRunner.run(strings);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: We are trying to implement it with spring cli's command CliCommand annotation. 
It seems that each command is like "main" which already parse the arguments fro command line

Comment: so this is something different than the Spring Boot CommandLine Runner; sorry, never have used that

Comment: Neither approach is remotely reasonable.... Just going to the 3 story high switch statement, ... I hate to say it, but it maintains better.  Dependency injection, sure 100%, once you pass beyond that though...

Answer (score 4):

Strangely there is not a built-in mechanism to select a set of CommandLineRunner. By default all of them are executed.

I have reused - maybe improperly - the Profile mechanism, that is I have annotated each CommandLineRunner with  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile("mycommand"), and I select the one I want to execute with the System property -Dspring.profiles.active=mycommand

For more information on the Profile mechanism, please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: That worked very well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44482525/986160 but using injection and less configuration.

Having a similar requirement, what has worked for me is to have one `CommandLineApps` class implementing `CommandLineRunner`, then inject all my other command line runners as `@Component` and use the first argument to delegate to one of the injected runners. Please note that the injected ones should not extend `CommandLineRunner` and not be annotated as `@SpringBootAppplication`.

**Important**: be careful though if you put the call in a crontab one call will destroy the previous one if it is not done.

Here is an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CommandLineApps implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private FetchSmsStatusCmd fetchSmsStatusCmd;

    @Autowired
    private OffersFolderSyncCmd offersFolderSyncCmd;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CommandLineApps.class,  args);
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {

        if (args.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        List<String> restOfArgs = Arrays.asList(args).subList(1, args.length);

        switch (args[0]) {
            case "fetch-sms-status":
                fetchSmsStatusCmd.run(restOfArgs.toArray(new String[restOfArgs.size()]));
                break;
            case "offers-folder-sync":
                offersFolderSyncCmd.run(restOfArgs.toArray(new String[restOfArgs.size()]));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class FetchSmsStatusCmd {

    [...] @Autowired dependencies    

    public void run(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            logger.error("Wrong number of arguments");
            return;
        }
        [...]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple CommandLineRunner in single file or application. Which one needs to be executed ( calling "run" method) decided by the one and only - Order (@Order annotation).
If you need to execute multiple CommandLineRunner, write them, pass the value to Order annotation.

```
@Bean
    @Order(value = 1)
    public CommandLineRunner demo1(CustomerRepository customerRepository){
        return (args) ->{
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Viji", "Veerappan"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Dhinesh", "Veerappan"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Senbagavalli", "Veerappan"));
        };
    }



@Order(value = 2)
    public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository customerRepository){
        return (args) ->{

            // Save all the customers
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Mahith", "Saravanan"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Pooshi", "Saravanan"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Dharma", "Saravanan"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Mookayee", "Veerayandi"));
            customerRepository.save(new Customer("Chellammal", "Kandasamy"));

            //fetch all customer
            log.info("Fetching all the customers by findAll()");
            log.info("----------------------------------------");
            for(Customer customer : customerRepository.findAll()){
                log.info(customer.toString());
            }
            log.info("");

            //fetch one customer by Id
            log.info("Fetch one customer Id by findById(1L)");
            log.info("----------------------------------------");
            log.info(customerRepository.findById(1L).toString());
            log.info("");

            //fetch by last name
            log.info("Fetch all customers that have lastname = Saravanan");
            log.info("---------------------------------------------------");
            for(Customer customer: customerRepository.findByLastName("Saravanan")){
                log.info(customer.toString());
            }
            /*customerRepository.findByLastName("Saravanan").forEach( saravanan ->{
                saravanan.toString();
            });*/
        };
    }
```